# Why does array state item using hooks only updates component when using spread?

Tags: reactjs

I don't understand why a component only re-renders when using spread operator in an array state item as follows:

I first create a dynamic array state with false values:

```
const [openList, setOpenList] = React.useState(props.navBarItems.map((item, index) => false));
```

Option 1

```
function handleClick(index) {
       let newOpenList = [...openList]
       newOpenList[index] = !openList[index]
       console.log(newOpenList) // prints the same in both options
       setOpenList(newOpenList);

}
```

Option 2:

```
function handleClick(index) {
       let newOpenList = openList
       newOpenList[index] = !openList[index]
       console.log(newOpenList) // prints the same in both options
       setOpenList(newOpenList);
}
```

I used a console.log in render() (there's probably a better way to know if component updated using hooks) and it is only called when using option 1.

Comment: Option 2 will not cause a re-render because you're doing a state-mutation. ie:, you are not creating a new state object, and you are just making updates to the existing object in reference. Components only re-render when you provide a brand-new state, which is what you're doing with the spread operator. You're creating a brand-new array and then setting-state with that new array which is a valid state update.

Comment: In the second one, the new array is a modified version of the original. So when setState determines if it needs to rerender it sees that it’s the same object and doesn’t do anything

Comment: @ChristopherNgo you are right, the thing is that: "In JavaScript, arrays and objects are reference types. This means that when a variable is assigned an array or object, what gets assigned to the variable is a reference to the location in memory where the array or object was stored."

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/https-medium-com-gladchinda-hacks-for-creating-javascript-arrays-a1b80cb372b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because on option 2 you are mutating the `openList` array. When you do `let newOpenList = openList` you are not creating a new variable, you are just assigning `openList` to `newOpenList`. Even after adding one more item to `newOpenList`, when react compare the `oldOpenList === openList` this return true, and react does not update.

On option 1, when you do `[...openList]` it creates a new array with the same items of `openList`. As it will be a new variable, when react compares `oldOpenList === openList` it returns false, and react update.

You can have a more completed answer about that [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove/)

Comment: You are right, the thing is that: "In JavaScript, arrays and objects are reference types. This means that when a variable is assigned an array or object, what gets assigned to the variable is a reference to the location in memory where the array or object was stored."

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/https-medium-com-gladchinda-hacks-for-creating-javascript-arrays-a1b80cb372b/